# Where in my code am I messing up when trying to buffer a string?

Tags: java

I am a beginner in Java language and I recently found this string program about buffering strings.  I typed the code into my IDE, however there is a syntax error that keeps popping up, making it unable to compile the code. The error appears to be with the count7lt variable in my last for loop.

Here is the code:

```
public class StringBuffer{
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      countTo_N_Improved();
   }
   private final static int MAX_LENGTH=30;
   private static String buffer = "";
   private static void emit(String nextChunk) {
      if(buffer.length() + nextChunk.length() > MAX_LENGTH) {
         System.out.println(buffer);
         buffer = "";  
      }
      buffer += nextChunk;
   }
   private static final int N=100;
   private static void countTo_N_Improved() {
      for (int count=2; count7lt;=N; count=count+2) {
         emit(" " + count);
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Please post the full compiler error. Also, please do not use HTML code (`&lt;`) in your code.

Comment: the ```7lt;``` should be ```<```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just replace count7lt;=N with count <=N should do it.
Probably some problem while copy and pasting, that escaped the < character and replaced it with 7lt; which stands for less than.

Answer (score 2):

Your last for loop has too many semicolons.

My guess is you were copying code which is okay--but if you look closely you can see that it doesn't fit the standard formatting of the for(;;) loop and that it contains a variable that you didn't create.

Java is really good at catching problems early and telling you as well as it can what is wrong.  Reading and considering errors is important.

Comment: He even told the exact term that throws the error didn't he? What is your problem?

Comment: Did that come across as I had a problem?  I didn't mean it to.  I was trying to be helpful but perhaps you are right.  I'll try to blunt it a tad more :)

Comment: Thanks for the feedback guys!

Comment: The version of now I like a lot more. One up for that one ;)